# Differences between a Markov chain in discrete time and a Martingale?

Tags: statistics, markov-chains

First of all Im just interested in stochastic processes (not a math student), so sorry for any misunderstandings or a probably very simple question.
I try to figure out whats the key differences between a Markov chain in discrete time and a martingale are. As far as I understand these processes and other posts I would summarize the differences as follows:

1. A Martingale makes a statement only about the future mean, not about the entire probability distribution
2. If the transition probability in a markov chain to stay in the current state is less than 1, its not a Martingale
3. A Markov chain is completely independent of the past, a Martingale is not necessarily independent of the past

Is this correct and are there further differences or maybe also similarities? Thanks for any help

Comment: The 3rd point makes me feels a bit uneasy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your #1 is more or less true, except that you should keep in mind that it is a statement about the future mean conditional on the history of the process. Basically, on average, each *increment* of a martingale is zero.

Your #2 is false. For example, the simple symmetric random walk in 1D is a martingale. A Markov chain with increment starting at a particular state having a nonzero average is not a martingale.

Your #3 is a bit vague but essentially true. For example, one can define a martingale in which $X_{n+1}=X_n \pm f_n(X_0,\dots,X_n)$ with equal probability, where these functions $f_n$ can be a wide variety of things, for example any bounded Borel measurable function.

(Here when I say "is a martingale" I technically mean "is a martingale with respect to the natural filtration".)

Comment: Thanks. Can I improve #2? So can I make any assumption about the transition probabilities, so a Markov chain is not a Martingale? For example if I have a 2 state Markov Chain in discrete time with probabilities P(0|0) = 0.1 and P(1|0) = 0.9 and P(1|1) = P(0|1) = 0.5 its not "fair", so its not a Martingale, correct?

Comment: @ManuelK That's right.